# iOS - Serial communication integration into Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, serial-port

Alright, so I found [this tutorial](http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial) for accessing the serial port on the iPhone. I incorporated the code into my Xcode project by creating a `Serial.c` file.  Now how do I get the get output of the serial communication into a `textview`?  My Xcode project can be found [here](http://www.chrisrjones.com/files/KegCop-Test.zip)

Comment: So I am able to receive serial data from the Arduino to the iPhone now.  Does anyone know how I can put this data in a text view?

Comment: What did you use? The links expired...

Comment: Perhaps this? http://redpark.com/products/developers/serial-cable-sdk-faq-download/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible w/out Apple's security coprocessor on the other end of the serial cable.  In order for an iOS device to begin communicating with an accessory, the accessory must have a security co-processor.

You might want to look at the [Redpark](http://redpark.com/c2db9.html) serial cable which does have the auth chip as required by Apple.  This would be a good solution for prototyping or hacking about.

Comment: what about this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwVoir5HSo4 and this http://hcgilje.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/iphone-serial-communication/

Comment: just ran across this, looks pretty legit. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wgSThF9Ueg

Comment: From a YouTube commenter: "jailbroke the iPhone, installed apt and mobileterminal for it, then used apt to install screen. I just repinned a 30 pin to USB connector to use serial instead of USB, then wrote a quick sketch that prints the "Hello iPhone" message to the arduino serial. From there I just ran "screen /dev/tty.iap 9600" in mobileterminal to get the scrolling text. I had to use two 560 ohm resistors for the iPhone serial rx though, as I didn't feel like going to shit assed radio shack for a 1k."

Comment: So it looks like the key step is jailbreaking the iphone.

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternative that allows COM port use, ***without*** jailbreaking the iOS devices, and ***without*** requiring custom application development.

Redpark sells the [Lightning Console Cable (L2-RJ45V3)](https://redpark.com/lightning-console-cable-l2-rj45v/).  Unlike the cable with a DB-9 connector, this "Console Cable" is supported by terminal applications that are available today in the app store:

- [`Termius`](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/termius-terminal-ssh-client/id549039908)
- [`Get Console`](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/get-console/id412067943)

The RJ45 side follows the ["Cisco Console Port"](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/7000-series-routers/12223-14.html#toc-hId--715334043) wiring specification.  See [visual](https://pinoutguide.com/SerialPorts/cisco_cons_pinout.shtml) listing at non-Cisco site.

The signals are true RS-232, so if you want to connect directly to TTL-level logic, you'll need a converter (annoying, but easy).

If you just need to connect it to a DB9 serial port, just grab a [converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00006IRQA) ... typically under $5.

The RedPark cables are expensive ... but so is the MFi program.  I blame Apple for not supporting USB serial, and for not supporting the Bluetooth SPP profile, either of which would end this craziness.